# interactive call of functions from dynamic library without waiting for return (python,ctypes)

Tags: c++, multithreading, ctypes, interactive

I'm doing interface of my simple C++ physical-simulation and visualization library to python. I would like to use it in interactive way - meaning to **adjust parameters by calling functions from python interpret parameters while the simulation/visualization is running**)

currently the [non-interactive scrip](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/blob/master/python/test_Vis3D.py) looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pyVis3D as vis

# inititalization
vis.lib.initWindow()  

# modify visualization state - must do before call vis.lib.loop()
ts   = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
poss = np.transpose( np.stack([ np.sin(ts), np.cos(ts), np.sin(ts*3) ]), (1,0) ).copy()
vis.polyline( poss )

# loop of visualization window update 
vis.lib.loop(1000000) # I have to wait for return, cannot change anything interactively
```

I would like instead something like this in python interpret:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> import pyVis3D as vis
>> vis.lib.initWindow()   # inititalization 
>> vis.lib.loop(1000000)  # run loop

# modify state of vis.lib while vis.lib.loop() is running  
>> ts   = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
>> poss = np.transpose( np.stack([ np.sin(ts), np.cos(ts), np.sin(ts*3) ]), (1,0) ).copy()
>> vis.polyline( poss ) # I should see new curve in that window
```

Here is the [ctypes interface](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/blob/master/python/pyVis3D/c_interface.py) and here the [C++ library](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/blob/master/cpp/libs/Vis3D/Vis3D.cpp).

I guess solution have something to do with multi-threading, but I have no experience with that. I'm not even sure if this multi-threading should be on side of python or C++ or both.

---

Simple example (C++) ... only think what I want is `setGlobVar()` called from python terminal modify `glob_var` while `loop` is running, and `loop` output reflect the modified state of `glob_var`

```
double glob_var=0;

extern{

    // this function should run on background, write out state each 10 ms
    void loop(int n){
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
              SDL_delay( 10 );               // wait 10 ms
              printf( "%f \n", glob_var );   // each iteration write current state of glob_var
         }
    }

    // this function should be called from python terminal
    void setGlobVar( double f ){
        glob_var = f;   // change state of glob_var
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad.  Without seeing the code of your library, no one can tell you how to do make it work asynchronously like this, and even if you showed the code, the task is likely too large for this format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it inside single thread. You must use `multithreading` or `multiprocessing` for this purpose: one of the threads (`thread B`) should accept commands and run in (through running your dll's functions) and another thread (`thread A` - thread with main logic) should send those requests and check results from time to time.

Of course your dlls may do such work by themselves, but they don't as I can see (since your question exist).

Actually do not expect that in response to your question, someone will teach you to fully work with multithreading. This problem is too broad. There are books, articles and courses about multithreading. You may look to them.

Comment: thanks. So perhaps I should do it more in C++ rather than in python. I do not want "teach fully work with multithreading" ... I want just one really simple thing - I added example of what I want in C++